# Display sum and average of numbers 1 to 100

Tags: c#

I am trying to write a simple program in C# to display the sum and the average of the numbers 1 to 100. the output should look like...

```
the sum is 5050
the average is 50.5
```

I cant seem to get it to work properly though, the return value only returns the sum not the wording before it, I have tried other ways for it to display the message and sum and ave but they arent working. I am trying to do this using the model view view controller method, but cant understand where I am going wrong and how to get it to display the above result. my code is below.

```
class SumAndAverage
{
    public float sum = 0;
    public float ave = 0;


    public float SumAndAve()
    {

        for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
        {
            sum = sum + i;
            ave = sum / i;
        }

        return sum + ave;

    }

}
```

}

```
class SumAndAverageController
{
    IView view;
    SumAndAverage sumAndAverage;
    public SumAndAverageController(IView theView, SumAndAverage theSumAndAverage){
    view = theView;
    sumAndAverage = theSumAndAverage;
}
    public void Go()
    {
        view.Start();
        //mAndAverage.SetNumber(view.GetString("Please enter a number"));
        view.Show(sumAndAverage.SumAndAve());
        //view.Show(sumAndAverage.Result());
        view.Stop();
    }
}


class ConsoleView : IView
{
    public void Start()
    {
        Console.Clear();
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }



    public void Show<T>(T message)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(message);
    }

}


interface IView
{
    void Start();
    void Stop();
    void Show<T>(T message);
}


class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        new SumAndAverageController(new ConsoleView(), new SumAndAverage()).Go();
    }
}
```

Comment: [I downvoted because "It's not working" isn't a helpful problem description](http://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

namespace SumAndAverage
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var data = Enumerable.Range(1, 100);
            Console.WriteLine("the sum is " + data.Sum());
            Console.WriteLine("the average is " + data.Average());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you really think this is how a total newbie should learn?? As an alternative, yes, but now he knows absolutly nothing more about his actual problems! Only how to cheat by using SO as a magic coding service..

Comment: Yes, this is C#. He asked about C#. There is no magic here. If s/he wants to know about algorithms, that's a different topic. Specify a language? You get that language's method. This is SOF. It's about specific questions and getting specific answers.